# Razor+javascript syntax errors encountering ","

Tags: razor

My attempt to generate javascript with razor:

```
<script>
  var slides =
  [
    @foreach (var news in Model.News)
    {
      @:data.push(
      {
        fileID: @(news.FileID),
        preamble: "@(news.Preamble)",
        img: "/Admin/News/NewsPng/@(news.NewsID)"
      });
    }
  ];
</script>
```

I get syntax errors on

- The fileID line both on "@" (unexpected token) and the "," (; expected) at the end of the line.
- The preamble line on the "," (; expected)
- The img line, after the last quotation mark (; expected)
- }); line on ")" (unexpected token)
- The ]; line on "]" (syntax error)

It doesnt seem like visual studio 2012 accepts a lot of my razor code. Maybe it is also worth noting that I am using R# (if that is a problem).

In addition to the obvious question why all those error messages arises I also wonder what makes visual studio actually accept that I try to *run* this.

All those compilation errors, and visual studio actually *runs* it? Why?

When I run the code, I get the following error:

```
CS1646: Keyword, identifier, or string expected after verbatim specifier: @
```

and the fileID line is highlighted.

Razor is probably a really good thing, but this far it has given my some serious headache.  Maybe I am just doing something silly...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try `<text>`:

```
<script> 
  var slides = 
  [ 
    @foreach (var news in Model.News) 
    { 
      <text>
      data.push( 
      { 
        fileID: @(news.FileID), 
        preamble: "@(news.Preamble)", 
        img: "/Admin/News/NewsPng/@(news.NewsID)" 
      });
      </text>
    } 
  ]; 
</script>
```

But your syntax is wrong, you will get error in javascript.

**Added:**

Something like this will work:

```
<script> 
    var slides = [];
    @foreach (var news in Model.News) 
    { 
      <text>
      slides.push({...});
      </text>
    } 
</script>
```